# Organizing fragments for each activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have two activities, `MainActivity` and `UserActivity`. Each activity has 3 swipeable tabs, where each tab has its own fragment.

Each fragment contains the exact same layout but loads content into it differently. The tabs in `UserActivity` are the exact same tabs that exist in `MainActivity`.

Should I just have a total of 3 fragments, used for both activities or have 6 fragments where 3 are used for `MainActivity` and the other 3 are for `UserActivity`?

If I should only have a total of 3 fragments, how can I differentiate which activity is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good question and I think the answer is a little subjective. 
But anyway:

If both activities have the same 3 fragments and they have more or less the same functionalities you should only have 3 fragments and re-use them.

Fragments are especially useful because they can easily be reused and that's a perfect use case.

Only if their functionality would be a lot different you should distinguish between them.

How to differentiate ? Well that's pretty easy:

- Create a newInstace method for your fragments and pass a int (based on the type):

  ```
  public class TestFragment {
   public static TestFragment newInstance(int testInt) {
     TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putInt("testInt", testInt);
     fragment.setArguments(args);

     return fragment;
   }
  ...
  }
  ```
- To create a fragment use: `Fragment testFragment = TestFragment.newInstance(testInt);`
- Later to get the data passed in the newInstance method just use something like this: `getArguments().getInt("testInt", -1);`

Based on the int that you passed, you can filter/decide which data you would like to show/use.

EDIT:

If all the 3 fragments inside 1 activity are the same, just use 1 fragment for all the 6 tabs.

Distinguish witch activity is being used, doesn't make really sense... You can access the activity inside your fragment by calling `getActivity();`

Hope this helps...
Cheers